# Method to return a generic View type in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

making the jump into SwiftUI and hit a hurdle. For my app home screen I want a struct to sift through various states and return the appropriate View based on a condition.

In Swift I would usually apply some sort of 'Manager' object to review the data states and return a class that inherits from UIView - but trying to do the same same in SwiftUI is causing me some problems - Example here:

```
struct HomeScreenViewDirector {
     func fetchView() -> View {
        if someDataState {
            return PopulatedHomeScreen()
        } else {
            return EmptyView()
        }
    }
}
struct EmptyHomeScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            navigationBarTitle("Empty State")
        }
    }
}
struct PopulatedHomeScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
         navigationBarTitle("Populated State")
    }
}
```

Attempting to do this generates the error

`Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

on the `-> View` return type. From some research it looks like I could change this to `some View` and then wrap all my returns as `AnyView` but that feels like it's the wrong approach.

Any tips on how and why to handle this

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
struct HomeScreenViewDirector {
    let someDataState: Bool // << seems should be this as well?

    @ViewBuilder
     func fetchView() -> some View {
        if someDataState {
            PopulatedHomeScreen()
        } else {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}
```